# How to get virtual memory page size without using callsystem?

Tags: java, operating-system

I want to measure virtual memory page size without using call Systems.
I knew we can measure it by `java.lang.reflect.Field` and `sun.misc.Unsafe`, but we don`t want to use call System like:

```
unsafe.pageSize();
```

Any Help?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need this?

Comment: because it is school project

Comment: Seems completely pointless to me. There is nothing useful you can do with the virtual memory page size in Java, and I'm not aware of any internal way to get it other than ai the means you've proscribed.